# How can you force @google-cloud/datastore to use 'http' when you query your datastore emulator

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, google-cloud-datastore

I have a node + vuejs app from which I'm trying to query my local db (created using datastore emulator).

My code is something like this

```
const { Datastore } = require('@google-cloud/datastore')
const datastore = new Datastore({
        apiEndpoint: "http://localhost:<port>",
        projectId: <my_project_name>
      })
```

I then try to run one of the sample queries on Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/metadataqueries#datastore-datastore-namespace-run-query-nodejs)

My output shows there is a successful connection but then I get the following error in the console

```
POST https://localhost:<port>/$rpc/google.datastore.v1.Datastore/RunQuery net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

From the error, I see that it has changed `http://localhost:<port>` to `https://localhost:<port>` i.e it is forcing a protocol of `https` for my local host which then obviously fails.

Is there something/option that I have to specify to ensure that it uses `http` when I'm making local calls or using the datastore emulator?

Comment: This might be a problem with the environment variables you are using with the emulator, try setting it like this: `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=http://localhost:8081` following the instructions of [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#manually_setting_the_variables), let me know if this works.

Comment: @RafaelLemos - thanks for the response but deliberately didn't want to use ```http://localhost:8081``` which per documentation is the default port. Documentation says you can start the data emulator with your own port via the flag ```--host-port``` and then pass it to the Datastore invocation via ```apiEndpoint```. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I added the port in my comment but you can try just not adding it to the host variable and adding the port as you mentioned, this might force the use to http, you will however need to keep the localhost, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and am posting it in case someone else has the issue.

I started going through the code itself and discovered a reference to this [link](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-nodejs/blob/master/client-libraries.md#creating-the-client-instance). The page says

.....*By default, the client library will use gRPC, which is a binary tranport based on HTTP/2. It's Node.js implementation, @grpc/grpc-js, uses Node.js http2 module.
If you need to use the client library in non-Node.js environment or when gRPC cannot be used for any reason, you can use the HTTP/1 fallback mode. In this mode, a special browser-compatible transport implementation is used instead of gRPC transport.
**In browser context (if the window object is defined) the fallback mode is enabled automatically; set options.fallback to false** if you need to override this behavior*....

When I added `fallback:false` to the options, everything worked i.e. it no longer redirected to https and it connected to my data emulator.

I thought about it further and I believe this behavior is because my code was written in the `renderer process` for a Vuejs App which means there's a `windows` object. To confirm, I moved the code to the `main process` and did not include the `fallback` option and it worked.